# Odoo xml view how to show account_invoice invoices into another context of view and model

Tags: python, xml, odoo-10

I have an account.invoice model with `many2one` with model test.

The problem is I need to show the invoices with the test_id into the test view.

I create a method inside Test model to get all invoices that have the same test_id domain, That works at this point. But how the hell I show it into the Test view without saving it into the database, with a virtual field or calling the method.

Account invoice model only has the test_id relation
This is my test class.

```
class test(models.Model):
   def _invoices(self):
      return self.env['account.invoice'].search([('test_id','=',self.id)])

   name = fields.Char(string='Name',default=_set_name)
   book_number = fields.Integer(string='Book #',default=_set_book)
   year = fields.Integer(string='Year',size=10)
   month = fields.Integer(string='Month',size=10)
   status = fields.Boolean(string='Status',default=False)
```

My view in the xml:

```
<record model="ir.ui.view" id="test_form">
        <field name="name">Test Form</field>
        <field name="model">test</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <form string="Test Form Yay" version="7.0" >
                <sheet attrs="{'readonly':[('status','=',True)]}">
                    <group><h1>Book #<field name="book_number"/></h1></group>
                    <group><field name="name"/></group>
                    <group><field name="month"/></group>
                    <group><field name="year"/></group>
                </sheet>
            </form>

            <div id="invoices">
                <!-- In theory the account.invoice invoices needs render here -->
            </div>
        </field>
    </record>
```

Comment: You can use compute field for that. it will not store in database.